# Hibernate + H2 Database + SpringBoot: Pre-existing tables in database are always dropped & re-created upon start, even for hbm2ddl = validate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I have a problem regarding the proper setup of a database. The behavior I observe is what I would excpect for "hbm2ddl.auto = create-drop" or "ddl-auto = create-drop." However, I explicitly set "hbm2ddl.auto = validate" and deleted ddl-auto (and tried every other combination of these two and validate), but still get the same behavior as for "create-drop".

First, what I want:

- I want to store data, let's say "MachineData" in a h2 database.
- I want to upload the data just once, by using the h2 interface
  in the browser (or by using an import.sql file).
- An application will use the data in the database, but won't modify
  anything

My problem:

- I create the table "MachineData" manually via the H2 interface and
  load some data with sql statements (see below).
- When I start my application however, the "MachineData" table that I manually
  created and filled with data is dropped.
- If I provided an import.sql file, the table and data is re-created.
  When the application is finished, the tables are dropped again.
  Hence, my database is empty, but the application worked.
- If I do not provide an import.sql file, the application will throw an
  error since the tables are not present.
- I tried every possible combination of hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
  and/or/ hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate. However, the results stays
  the same: tables are always dropped during start of the application.

UPDATED(1):
UPDATED(2):

My database is configured using @Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    private final Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseConfig(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("datasource.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("jpa.hibernate.dialect"));
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("jpa.show-sql"));
        hibernateProperties.put("spring.jpa.generate-ddl", env.getProperty("jpa.generate-ddl"));             
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

I am using a .yaml for the hibernate properties:
UPDATE:

```
spring.profiles: run_GA
datasource:
  driver: org.h2.Driver
  url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/C:/Users/User/Document/MLDB;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
  username: sa
  password:
jpa:
  show-sql: false
  generate-ddl: true
  hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
entitymanager.packagesToScan: somePath.mapping
```

Regarding the mapping, I use the following class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Machinedata {

    public int timeInCycles;
    public double sensor01; 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "timeincycles")
    public int getTimeInCycles() {
        return timeInCycles;
    }

    public void setTimeInCycles(int timeInCycles) {
        this.timeInCycles = timeInCycles;
    }

    @Column(name = "sensor01")
    public double getSensor01() {
        return sensor01;
    }

    public void setSensor01(double sensor01) {
        this.sensor01 = sensor01;
    }
```

When I manually create a table in the h2 database, I use the following sql commands:

```
CREATE TABLE MACHINEDATA(Time IDENTITY AUTO_INCREMENT, sensor01 DOUBLE);
INSERT INTO Machinedata SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('myPath.csv');
```

The import.sql file exhibts the following command:

```
INSERT INTO Machinedata (timeincycles, sensor01) SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('myPath.csv');
```

I would expect the described behavior if I set hbm2ddl.auto = create-drop. However, as I mentioned above, hbm2ddl.auto = validate in my case. Do you have any ideas what is wrong in my code? Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to drop the following configs...

```
hibernate.ddl-auto: validate  
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate
```

...and just use this spring config instead, any updates or changes on your class will just update the current.

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Comment: Thank a lot for your feedback @imprezzeb . I tried that (please see the code update above). However, the result is still an error in the code; the table "MachineData" (which i manually set up in the database) gets wiped out once I start the application...

Comment: Hi, you are mixing .yaml config and java bean config resulting to config conflict. Remove this (hibernate.ddl-auto: validate  
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate) in your yaml file and add generate-ddl in .yaml.

Comment: Thanks again @imprezzeb . You are right - no good style. I did as you recommended, now the generate-ddl is in the .yaml and I deleted the other two (please see above). Unfortunately, the pre-existing table "MachineData" in h2 is still getting dropped at each start...

Comment: One last try, remove this hibernateProperties.put("spring.jpa.generate-ddl", env.getProperty("jpa.generate-ddl")); in your java bean config.

Comment: Thanks @imprezzeb . I tried that, but no luck; all the data is still getting deleted :D This is strange...

Comment: Yes, I made sure to enable the profile "run_GA". When I start the program with the import.sql, all the tables are setup and filled with data. I think this indicates that the "run_GA" is active; otherwise the @Configuration would cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will apply to Your code, it helped me a lot. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1374

I've set:

```
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
    spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
```

(spring.jpa was missing) and this setting were honored.
SpringBoot 2.1.3.RELEASE